# iPhone UI Design approach - was using Excel Filtering

Tags: iphone, ios, user-interface, navigation

I'm new to iPhone development and don't know what the best iPhone UI approach for my problem is.  That's where I was hoping you all could provide some input and guidance.

Here's the system & how it's currently used:
Right now, I have an Excel spreadsheet of data with four columns - Make, Model, Size, Value.  There are about 1,000 rows of data.  How the system is used in Excel is to use Filtering on the columns.  First, you select the Make from the filtered column (there are about 8 unique Makes), then select a Model (each Make has between 1 and 20 unique Models), then select the Size (each Model has about 20 unique Sizes), then use the associated Value.

If I were to create an HTML page and jQuery with AJAX, I'd have three SELECT elements and one DIV (or some kind of label).  When a Make is selected, populate the Models SELECT. Likewise, when a Model is selected, populate the Size SELECT.  Finally, when a Size is selected, display the associated Value in the DIV.  (Note, that when a Make is selected, I'd need to clear out the Value DIV and the Size SELECT in addition to the population of the Model SELECT. - appropriate action for selecting Size as well)

Now, given that, what do you recommend as a UI pattern for the iPhone?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do exactly that you describe for the HTML version, using a `UIPickerView` in each place where you would use and HTML `SELECT`. (The UIPickerView uses the "spinning wheel" metaphor to select from a list of values).

You could also use a single multi-component UIPickerView, where the first wheel is Make, the second Model, and the third Size. That works best if the names are short enough that you can fit all three (Make/Model/Size) in a single row on the screen.

Comment: Thanks David. I can't use a multi-component UIPickerView b/c the names are too long (Models can be quite long). In this case, I would use 3 UIPickerViews (stacked in the UI with Make/Model/Size labels above each picker). How can I have each UIPickerView show only one item when not in focus and when in focus, expand to show the "spinning wheel"? TIA for the terms to research. Alternatively, does Apple (or someone else) have samples that show how to use the UIPickerView in this way?  The only usage of UIPickerView I have seen is to always have it show as a list at the bottom of the screen.

Comment: One thing you can do is use 3 buttons to display the current selection, and have the pickerviews hidden. When you click a button, it pops up the corresponding pickerview (perhaps doing a slide in animation) and adds a "done" button to the UI. Clicking "done" makes the picker go away again.